# unable to set if else conditions with has-many through association in rails 4 view

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I am working on an application with has_many through association.
in `employee.rb`

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :inventories, through: :employee_inventories
end
```

in `inventory.rb`

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, through: :employee_inventories
end
```

in `employee_inventories.rb`

```
class EmployeeInventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :inventory
end
```

Everything is fine with this association. But when I implement if-elsif condition with accessing status column from employee_inventory. Like that

```
<% if (inventory.is_available == false && current_employee[:role] == 'INVENTORY') %>
     <% if(inventory.employee_inventories.collect{|e| e.status == 'REQUESTED'}) %>
           <%= link_to 'Allot', inventory_available_status_inventory_path(inventory,   :employee_inventory => { :status => 'ALLOTTED' }) %>
            <%= link_to 'Cancel', inventory_available_status_inventory_path(inventory, :employee_inventory => { :status => 'CANCELLED' } ) %>
     <% elsif (inventory.employee_inventories.collect{|e| e.status == 'ALLOTTED'}) %> 
            <%= link_to 'return'%>
      <% end %>
<% elsif inventory.is_available == true %>
     <%= link_to 'Request for inventory',request_inventories_inventory_path(inventory, :employee_inventory => { :employee_id => current_employee, :status => 'REQUESTED', :inventory_id => inventory}) %>
<% end %>
```

In code when update status of employee_inventory to REQUESTED. Everything goes fine but after when I update status to ALLOTTED then second elsif condition is unable to execute.

from `inventory.employee_inventories.collect{|e| e.status == 'ALLOTTED'}` 
Output:-

> [true]

I am confused why is it not executing in second time. Please guide me. Thank in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *condition is unable to execute*? What happens instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-collect) creates a new array containing the values returned by the block. You have one `employee_inventories`'s status as 'ALLOTTED', and since you're checking it in the `collect` block: `e.status == 'ALLOTTED' #=> true`, it creates an array with boolean `true` value: `[true]`.

To solve your issue you can either do:

```
inventory.employee_inventories.collect{|e| e.status }.include? 'ALLOTTED'
```

or check if any one employee inventory is set to allotted(if that's what you're doing here) using [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-any-3F) or [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) as per your requirement:

```
inventory.employee_inventories.any?{|e| e.status == 'ALLOTTED' }
# or
inventory.employee_inventories.all?{|e| e.status == 'ALLOTTED' }
```

Now, I'd recommend you to probably cleanup your logic to something like this. You don't really need to follow this as your question has already been answered above:

```
<% if inventory.is_available? %>
  <%= link_to 'Request for inventory',request_inventories_inventory_path(inventory, :employee_inventory => { :employee_id => current_employee, :status => 'REQUESTED', :inventory_id => inventory}) %>
<% elsif current_employee[:role] == 'INVENTORY' %>
  <% if inventory.employee_inventories.all?{|e| e.status == 'REQUESTED'} %>
    <%= link_to 'Allot', inventory_available_status_inventory_path(inventory,   :employee_inventory => { :status => 'ALLOTTED' }) %>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', inventory_available_status_inventory_path(inventory, :employee_inventory => { :status => 'CANCELLED' } ) %>
  <% elsif inventory.employee_inventories.all?{|e| e.status == 'ALLOTTED'} %> 
    <%= link_to 'return'%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```